# How do I reshape an array of data into an array of matrices of data?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a question that I suspect is trivial, but I have not stumbled onto any functions that have made such a solution obvious to me. Consider an array of the following form:

$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I want a simple way to partition this into matrices with identical dimension, which in this case, could be a set of four 2x2 matrices, resulting in

$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{13} & a_{14} \\
a_{23} & a_{24} \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{31} & a_{32} \\
a_{41} & a_{42} \\
\end{pmatrix} & 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{33} & a_{34} \\
a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, to generalize: I want a method to partition an $N\times N$ matrix into identical $d\times d$ submatrices, in exactly the way outlined here, and we assume of course that $d$ divides $N$. Could someone offer such a technique? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but unless I'm misunderstanding you this won't work in general. Consider the case Array[a, {8,8}], which I can reshape into a collection of 4x4 matrix of 2x2 matrices with ArrayReshape[Array[a, {8,8}], {2,2,2,2,2,2}]. The elements in this case will be partitioned incorrectly, as you can easily verify. Perhaps I'm not getting it?

Comment: Correy has been quickier than I.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Partition` does exactly what you want:

```
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {10, 10}];
```

[image]

```
Partition[mat, {5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Partition[mat, {2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: As suspected, with the right function the answer is trivial! Thanks very much friend :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I will not give explanation because I am in hurry

```
 m = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
 m // MatrixForm  
 Flatten[m]
 l = Partition[m, {2, 2}]
 l // MatrixForm
```

In the same time I think all this is self explanatory